# Parse a string as a list of words and parse characters

Tags: python, beginner, parsing, python-2.x

I'm trying to create a list from a string with items alternating between words and parse characters like `['Hello', ' ', 'World']`

Is there a built in function, existing module, or simpler way to achieve something like below? I'm interested in variable chars for parsing.

[sample.txt](http://pastebin.com/7gS3gJDW)

```
def parse_chars(string, chars):
    parse_set = {c for c in chars}
    string_list = []
    start = 0
    for index, char in enumerate(string):
        if char not in parse_set:
            if index - start > 0:
                word = string[start:index]
                string_list.append(word)
            string_list.append(char)
            start = index + 1
    document_len = len(string)
    if start != document_len:
        word = string[start:document_len]
        string_list.append(word)
    return string_list

filename = 'sample.txt'
with open(filename) as document_open:
    document_string = document_open.read()
alphanumeric = (map(chr, range(48, 58)) + 
                map(chr, range(65, 90)) +
                map(chr, range(97, 123)))

print parse_chars(document_string, alphanumeric)
```

> [' ', 'A', ' ', 'space', ' ', 'then', ' ', '3', ' ', 'blank', ' ', 'lines', '\n', '\n', '\n', '3', ' ', 'blank', ' ', 'spaces', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'end']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) says:

> If capturing parentheses are used in *pattern*, then the text of all groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting list.

For example:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.split('( )', 'hello world')
['hello', ' ', 'world']
```

If the string starts or ends with a separator, you get an empty string:

```
>>> re.split('( )', ' a b c ')
['', ' ', 'a', ' ', 'b', ' ', 'c', ' ', '']
```

You probably don't want these empty strings, so you should filter them out:

```
>>> [w for w in re.split('( )', ' a b c ') if w]
[' ', 'a', ' ', 'b', ' ', 'c', ' ']
```

So your `parse_chars` function would become:

```
[w for w in re.split('([^0-9A-Za-z])', string) if w]
```

For example:

```
>>> [w for w in re.split('([^0-9A-Za-z])', '10 green bottles!') if w]
['10', ' ', 'green', ' ', 'bottles', '!']
```